# How to build OneHot Decoder in python

Tags: python, numpy, decoding, one-hot-encoding

I have `encoded` my **images(masks)** with dimensions *(img_width x img_height x 1)* with `OneHotEncoder` in this way:

```
import numpy as np

def OneHotEncoding(im,n_classes):
  one_hot = np.zeros((im.shape[0], im.shape[1], n_classes),dtype=np.uint8)
  for i, unique_value in enumerate(np.unique(im)):
    one_hot[:, :, i][im == unique_value] = 1
  return one_hot
```

After doing some data manipulation with deep learning, `softmax` activation function will result in probabilities instead of `0` and `1` values, so in my Decoder I wanted to implement the following approach:

> 1. Threshold the output to obtain `0` or `1` only.
> 2. Multiply each channel with weight equal to the channel index.
> 3. take the max between labels along channels axis.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [[0.1,0.2,0,5],[0.2,0.4,0.7],[0.3,0.5,0.8]],
    [[0.3,0.6,0  ],[0.4,0.9,0.1],[0  ,0  ,0.2]],
    [[0.7,0.1,0.1],[0,6,0.1,0.1],[0.6,0.6,0.3]],
    [[0.6,0.2,0.3],[0.4,0.5,0.3],[0.1,0.2,0.7]]
])

# print(arr.dtype,arr.shape)

def oneHotDecoder(img):
    # Thresholding
    img[img<0.5]=0
    img[img>=0.5]=1
    # weigts of the labels
    img = [i*img[:,:,i] for i in range(img.shape[2])]
    # take the max label
    img = np.amax(img,axis=2)
    print(img.shape)
    return img

arr2 = oneHotDecoder(arr)
print(arr2)
```

### My questions is:

> 1. How to git rid of the error:
>      `line 15, in oneHotDecoder
>      img[img<0.5]=0 TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'`
> 2. Is there any other issues in my implementaion that you suggest to improve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos with commas and dots with some of your items (e.g. your first list should be `[0.1, 0.2, 0.5]` instead of `[0.1, 0.2, 0, 5]`).

The fixed list is:

```py
l = [
      [[0.1,0.2,0.5],[0.2,0.4,0.7],[0.3,0.5,0.8]],
      [[0.3,0.6,0  ],[0.4,0.9,0.1],[0  ,0  ,0.2]],
      [[0.7,0.1,0.1],[0.6,0.1,0.1],[0.6,0.6,0.3]],
      [[0.6,0.2,0.3],[0.4,0.5,0.3],[0.1,0.2,0.7]]
]
```

Then you could do:

```py
np.array(l)  # np.dstack(l) would work as well
```

Which would yield:

```py
array([[[0.1, 0.2, 0.5],
        [0.2, 0.4, 0.7],
        [0.3, 0.5, 0.8]],
       [[0.3, 0.6, 0. ],
        [0.4, 0.9, 0.1],
        [0. , 0. , 0.2]],
       [[0.7, 0.1, 0.1],
        [0.6, 0.1, 0.1],
        [0.6, 0.6, 0.3]],
       [[0.6, 0.2, 0.3],
        [0.4, 0.5, 0.3],
        [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]]])
```