# How can I one hot encode nii.gz files stored in two different folders?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, one-hot-encoding, medical-imaging, nifti

I have read all those images, which I am going to use for binary classification, and stored them in two different NumPy arrays. Now, I need to one hot encode these images, and then feed it to a Neural network.

I don't understand how I can one hot encode two different numpy arrays and then feed them to a neural network.

array_1 contains all the images that will be labelled as 1, and array_2 contains all the images that will be labelled as 0.

Comment: Why would you want to one-hot-encode images???

Comment: @John you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62114645/how-to-build-onehot-decoder-in-python) useful.

Answer (score 0):

The Python package [platipy](https://github.com/pyplati/platipy) has functionality to encode (multiple-valued) label maps.

To install:

```
pip install -U pip
pip install platipy
```

Here is a short example:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
from platipy.imaging.label.utils import binary_encode_structure_list

img_label_1 = sitk.ReadImage("img_label_1.nii.gz")
img_label_2 = sitk.ReadImage("img_label_2.nii.gz")
img_label_3 = sitk.ReadImage("img_label_3.nii.gz")
# etc., for however many labels you have

label_list = [img_label_1, img_label_2, img_label_3]

img_encoded = binary_encode_structure_list(label_list)
```

If you need to use numpy, then you can just convert this SimpleITK image into a 3D numpy array:

```
arr_encoded = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(img_encoded)
```

N.B. You can also decode an encoded label map (e.g. the output of your NN) using tools in platipy:

```
from platipy.imaging.label.utils import binary_decode_image

label_list = binary_decode_image(img_prediction_encoded)
```

Hope this helps!